# write regex for everything except a particular pattern for password in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regex pattern for validating a password.

```
var expression = /^[^\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\s\=\+\[\{\]\}\;\:\'\"\<\>\?\/\,\.\`\~\'][^\s]+$/
```

and it's working fine.

Now I need to change it in such a way that I can give extra characters to be allowed or blocked on top of this.

I tried the following code but it not working.

```
var blockchar = "t";
var allowchar = "b";     
var expression = '^' + blockchar + '[^\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\s\=\+\[\{\]\}\;\:\'\"\<\>\?\/\,\.\`\~\'' + allowchar + '][^\s]+$'
var regexp = new RegExp(expression);
var elmval = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
if (!elmval.match(regexp)) {
    return "validation failed";
}
```

Can anyone guide me on how to incorporate the two variables (`blockchar` and `allowchar`) in this? The values in `blockchar` should be blocked and the value in `allowchar` should be allowed.

Comment: The first step is to understand how the initial expression works.

Comment: i modified the first expression as per my understandings. If anything wrong please help me to correct it.

Comment: What are the requirements of the initial expression?

Comment: this will validating the password.

Comment: Yes, but what characters you want to allow?

Comment: that i will provide dynamically. here   var blockchar = "t";
    var allowchar = "b";  if the user wants to exclude something apart from the validation already provided he can use blockchar,allowchar

Comment: I ask these questions because your initial pattern looks strange. However, I will post a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different ways to allow or forbid characters in a string. Lets see 3 basic examples:

- example 1: you give allowed characters in a character class

  `/^[a-zA-Z0-9@]+$/`

here, only letters, numbers and arobase are allowed, anchors at the begining and at the end ensure that the whole string must match the pattern.

- example 2: you give unwanted characters in a character class (using a negated character class `[^.....]`)

  `/^[^&#='")(]+$/`

all characters are allowed except `&` `#` `=` `'` `"`

- example 3: you check if the string contain an unwanted character

  `/[&#='")(]/`

if the result of the match is false and the string length is not null (or the size you want), then your string is valid.

**how to allow new characters:**

with example 1, it's easy, you put it in the character class:

```
var charclass = 'a-zA-Z0-9@';
var allowchars = '{}';
var regexp = new RegExp('^[' + charclass + allowchars + ']+$');
```

with example 2, it is more difficult because removing a character from the class is not easy. A way is to use an alternation:

```
var charclass = '[^&#=\'")(]';
var allowchars = '&#';
var regexp = new RegExp('^(?:' + charclass + '|[' + allowchars + '])+$');
```

With example 3, same problem than example 2, you need to remove the characters from the class. You can use a negative lookahead instead before the class:

```
var charclass = '[^&#=\'")(]';
var allowchars = '&#';
var regexp = new RegExp('^(?![' + allowchars + '])' + charclass );
```

**how to forbid characters:**

example 1: You don't touch to the original class but you add a negative lookahead (not followed by):

```
var charclass = '[a-zA-Z0-9@]+';
var blockchars = 'Yz8';
var regexp = new RegExp('^(?!.*[' + blockchars + '])' + charclass + '$');
```

characters `Y` `z` `8` are always in the character class, but the negative lookahead make the pattern fail if one these is present in the string.

example 2:

You can use the same precedant trick, or you can add forbidden characters to the (negated) character class:

```
var charclass = '^&#=\'")(';
var blockchars = 'Yz8';
var regexp = new RegExp('^[' + charclass + blockchars + ']+$');
```

example 3: You can add characters directly at the end of the class too.

With these examples, you can easily build your code to allow characters and forbid other characters dynamically:

example 1:

```
var charclass = 'a-zA-Z0-9@';
var allowchars = '{}';
var blockchars = 'Yz8';
var regexp = new RegExp('^(?!.*[' + blockchars + '])[' + charclass + allowchars + ']+$');
```

example 2:

```
var charclass = '^&#=\'")(';
var allowchars = '&#';
var blockchars = 'Yz8';
var regexp = new RegExp('^(?:[' + charclass + blockchars + ']|[' + allowchars + '])+$');
```

example 3:

```
var charclass = '^&#=\'")(';
var allowchars = '&#';
var blockchars = 'Yz8';
var regexp = new RegExp('^(?![' + allowchars + '])[' + charclass + blockchars + ']');
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a detailed answer for this. From your answer i concluded a pattern as shown below but it not validating accordingly.  var allowchar = "!";
        var charclass = 'a-zA-Z0-9@';
        var blockchars = 'Yz8';
        var regexp = new RegExp('^(?!.*[' + blockchars + '])' + '[' + charclass + eallowexception + ']' + '$'); which shows wrong answer.

Comment: @user833985: `eallowexception` is not defined (a typo?), and you forget the `+` after the character class.

Comment: sorry..it was a typo. but even  `var allowchar = "!"; var charclass = 'a-zA-Z0-9@'; var blockchars = 'Yz8'; var regexp = new RegExp('^(?!.*[' + blockchars + '])' + '[' + charclass + allowchar + ']' + '$');` not working.

Comment: @user833985: The +, the +! you forgot the `+` quantifier after the last character class.

Comment: thanks a lot!! `var regexp = new RegExp('^(?!.*[' + blockchars + '])([' + charclass + ']|[' + allowchar + '])+$');` works...great help..u  rocks..

Comment: @user833985: `var regexp = new RegExp('^(?!.*[' + blockchars + '])[' + charclass + allowchar + ']+$');` works too.

Comment: what is the difference between `([' + charclass + ']|[' + allowchar + '])` and `'[' + charclass + allowchar + ']` ?

Comment: @user833985: The difference is that `charclass` is a negated character class (you are in case of example 2, I hope), if you write `'[' + charclass + allowchar + ']'` you remove `allowchar` from allowed characters.

Comment: @user833985: I added example for the three cases.